# Unable to string.Format a C# multiline verbatim string when escaping curly braces

Tags: c#, string, verbatim-string

I am having issue with String.Format on a verbatim string with escaped curly braced.

It's raising a `FormatError() Exception:Message: System.FormatException : Input string was not in a correct format.`

```
    String s = $@"{{ ""ver"": ""1.0"",""userId"": ""{0}""}}";
    String.Format(s, "1234")
```

Comment: Why are you using string.Format over string interpolation?

Comment: Don't use `string.Format` **or** string interpolation to generate JSON. Create an anonymous object and use JSON.NET instead.

Comment: I only need to generate a json string encoded in a specifc format for specifc test case. I don't think using JSON.NET library add value here.

Comment: I disagree @SwissFr. a) If you did it that way you'd avoid having to ask this question. b) If the `userId` has contents that require escaping / encoding for JSON then your current code won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the C# string interpolation special character "$", however, you are using positional parameters in your template.

It should be:-

```
String s = @"{{ ""ver"": ""1.0"",""userId"": ""{0}""}}";

String.Format(s, "1234").Dump();
```

Or just:-

```
var userId = 1234;

String s = $@"{{ ""ver"": ""1.0"",""userId"": ""{userId}""}}";
```

If your intention is to generate JSON output, a more appropriate method would be to create your object and serialize it using the `Newtonsoft.Json` package:-

```
var x = new
{
    ver = "1.0",
    userId = "1234"
};

var s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x);
```